# How to fix 'Cannot access private member declared in class' error in Unreal & C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

I am currently learning Unreal and working with C++ and when creating a collision box I am receiving an 'Error C2248: 'UPrimitiveComponent::bGenerateOverlapEvents': cannot access private member declared in class 'UPrimitiveComponent'
The error is showing at line 18 in the ShipController.cpp file.

When reading around it was suggested that instead of using 'bGenerateOverlapEvents' to use 'SetGenerateOverlapEvents' instead however whilst this compiled correctly the collision box didn't not function properly.

Ship Controller Header File:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "ShipController.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class BASICSHOOTER_API AShipController : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    AShipController();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UShapeComponent* CollisionBox;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float Speed = 10.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category="Spawning")
            TSubclassOf<class ABulletController> BulletBlueprint;

    void Move_XAxis(float AxisValue);
    void Move_YAxis(float AxisValue);
    void OnShoot();

    FVector CurrentVelocity;

    bool Died;
    UFUNCTION()
    void OnOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult);
};
```

Ship Controller Cpp file

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "ShipController.h"
#include "BulletController.h"
#include "EnemyController.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"


// Sets default values
AShipController::AShipController()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    CollisionBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
    CollisionBox->bGenerateOverlapEvents = true;
    CollisionBox->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &AShipController::OnOverlap);

    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AShipController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AShipController::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    if (!CurrentVelocity.IsZero())
    {
        FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation() + Speed * CurrentVelocity * DeltaTime;

        SetActorLocation(NewLocation);

    }

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AShipController::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveX", this, &AShipController::Move_XAxis);
    InputComponent->BindAxis("MoveY", this, &AShipController::Move_YAxis);
    InputComponent->BindAction("Shoot", IE_Pressed, this, &AShipController::OnShoot);
}

void AShipController::Move_XAxis(float AxisValue)
{
    CurrentVelocity.X = AxisValue * 100.0f;
}

void AShipController::Move_YAxis(float AxisValue)
{
    CurrentVelocity.Y = AxisValue * 100.0f;
}

void AShipController::OnShoot()
{
    UWorld* World = GetWorld();

    if (World)
    {
        FVector Location = GetActorLocation();
        World->SpawnActor<ABulletController>(BulletBlueprint, Location, FRotator::ZeroRotator);
    }
}

void AShipController::OnOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComponent, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (OtherActor->IsA(AEnemyController::StaticClass()))
    {
        Died = true;
        this->SetActorHiddenInGame(true);

        UGameplayStatics::SetGamePaused(GetWorld(), true);

    }

}
```

Enemy Controller Header File

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "EnemyController.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class BASICSHOOTER_API AEnemyController : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AEnemyController();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UShapeComponent* RootBox;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    float Speed = -200.0f;
};
```

Enemy Controller Cpp File

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "EnemyController.h"
#include "Components/BoxComponent.h"


// Sets default values
AEnemyController::AEnemyController()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    RootBox = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Root"));
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AEnemyController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AEnemyController::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation();

    NewLocation.X += Speed * DeltaTime;
    SetActorLocation(NewLocation);

    if (NewLocation.X < -600.0f)
    {
        this->Destroy();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be when an object of class EnemyController touches an object of class ShipController that the game will pause and that the object of class ShipController will be hidden in game.

Comment: Well, why do you think you can use `bGenerateOverlapEvents` in tge first place? Is there some piece of documentation that says so? And why do you think proper functioning of the collision box has anything to do with the titular question? Are yoy sure there is *another* way to fix the private member error, one that magically makes the collision box work?

Comment: Are you sure that's a **Minimal** example? Also, the error seems pretty obvious. You can't do `CollisionBox->bGenerateOverlapEvents = true;` because you can't even do `CollisionBox->bGenerateOverlapEvents` outside of the `bGenerateOverlapEvents`'s class. The setter should do it, but if the program does not function correctly, you have a bug in your code and should probably ask a separate question. Remember - "*doesn't work*" is not a description.

Comment: @n.m. The tutorial I was following used the `bGenerateOverlapEvents` and the collision box within in that worked. However I do agree it doesn't seem like it should and using `SetGenerateOverlapEvents` would probably be a better way forwards.

Comment: @Fureeish Apologies on the example I did go quite a bit overboard. Thank you for pointing me in another direction, I'll dig deeper and see if I can find what I need to do,

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with unreal, but I can tell you from experience that `cannot access private member declared in class` usually is what it says it is. Whatever you're trying to access isn't allowed. Why? I couldn't tell you. Just look over the header for that class if you have it, and try to figure out what you're supposed to do instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `SetGenerateOverlapEvents(true);` instead of `bGenerateOverlapEvents = true;` did work.
For some reason I had set the objects at different heights and the collision boxes were not colliding which is why it didn't appear to work.
Thanks for the comments and advice!